How to extract text from a PDF file using python and PyMuPDF
I am trying to write a converter for a pdf file, starting with just text.
The goal is to extract:
the font
the location of the start of each block of text
each letter and the relative positions

additionally, if possible, I would like to get the current font, and to extract images.
I don't yet need to do anything with the information, just to have the right framework to work from.
I have written the following code which appears to traverse the text, but I am only jumping forward with a constant width, and I want to get the actual advance that the pdf specifies.
import sys
import fitz  # PyMuPDF

def extract_text_with_deltas(pdf_path):
    doc = fitz.open(pdf_path)
    
    for page_num in range(len(doc)):
        page = doc[page_num]
        previous_x, previous_y = None, None
        
        print(f"--- Start of Page {page_num + 1} ---")
        
        text_info = page.get_text("dict")  # Get text as a dictionary with structure
        
        for block in text_info['blocks']:
            if 'lines' not in block:
                continue  # Skip non-text blocks
            
            for line in block['lines']:
                for span in line['spans']:
                    font_size = span['size']  # Font size used in the span
                    span_text = span['text']
                    bbox = span['bbox']
                    x0, y0 = bbox[0], bbox[1]
                    span_width = bbox[2] - bbox[0]
                    num_chars = len(span_text)
                    
                    # Calculate approximate width of each character
                    char_width = span_width / num_chars if num_chars > 0 else 0
                    
                    for i, char in enumerate(span_text):
                        # Calculate position of each character
                        char_x0 = x0 + i * char_width
                        char_y0 = y0
                        
                        # Calculate deltas
                        delta_x = char_x0 - previous_x if previous_x is not None else 0
                        delta_y = char_y0 - previous_y if previous_y is not None else 0
                        
                        print(f"Character: '{char}', Delta X: {delta_x:.2f}, Delta Y: {delta_y:.2f}")
                        
                        # Update the previous coordinates
                        previous_x, previous_y = char_x0, char_y0

        print(f"--- End of Page {page_num + 1} ---\n")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        print("Usage: python extract_pdf_text.py <path_to_pdf>")
    else:
        pdf_path = sys.argv[1]
        extract_text_with_deltas(pdf_path)


Any API would be fine, though some are proprietary and require libraries. I just want to be able to extract sequentially, everything in the file, focusing first on just text. So if another API is better, I would be happy to switch. I would also be happy to switch to C++.

Not clear to me what your really want. It does look like that you need the output of page.get_text("rawdict"). Gives you all font and position of text and the images. Note: I am a maintainer and the original creator of PyMuPDF.
